# Python: Check if list of named tuples contains particular attribute value

Tags: python, list, namedtuple

I have a list of named tuples:

```
from collections import namedtuple

T = namedtuple('T', ['attr1', 'attr2', 'attr3', 'attr4'])
t1 = T('T1', 1, '1234', 'XYZ')
t2 = T('T2', 2, '1254', 'ABC')
t3 = T('T2', 2, '1264', 'DEF')
l = [t1, t2, t3]
```

I want to check if an element exists in the list `T` where `attr1 = 'T2'`.

Checking if the list contains such an element by doing:

```
any(x for x in l if x.attr1 == 'T2')
```

only returns the information whether such a namedtuple is in the list or not.
I would like to also pop this namedtuple from the list.
One way of doing it is:

```
if any(x for x in l if x.attr1 == 'T2'):
   result = [x for x in l if x.attr1 == 'T2'].pop()
```

However, I don't like this solution, since I'm looping over the list `l` twice.

Is there any better/more-elegant way of doing this?

Comment: Not directly an answer, but the usual `any` expression for testing the existence of such an element would be `any(x.attr1 == 'T2' for x in l)`, not what you have. What you're doing is unintentionally relying on the fact that your namedtuples are considered true when treated as booleans. In fact, the genexp you've written is more appropriate for extracting a matching namedtuple than for testing existence!

Answer (score 3):

How about an old-school for loop? Simple, elegant, and you loop only once.

```
for x in l:
    if x.attr1 == 'T2':
        break

result = x
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need one item and don't necessarily want to pop, you can use [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) with your existing generator expression:

```
result = next(x for x in l if x.attr1 == 'T2')
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use `next`:

```
try:
    result = next(t for t in l if t.attr1 == 'T2')
except StopIteration:
    result = None

result
# T(attr1='T2', attr2=2, attr3='1254', attr4='ABC')
```

Comment: Same as `result = next((t for t in l if t.attr1 == 'T5'), None)`, only longer. Using bare `except` is a bad idea, too.

Comment: @Psidom I downvoted it mainly because your answer was teaching bad practice (bare `except`).

Answer (score 1):

If it is allowed to get the result as an array:

```
result = filter(lambda x: x.attr1 == 'T2', l)
```

Or if you just want to get one then:

```
result = filter(lambda x: x.attr1 == 'T2', l).pop()
```